# Rigged Animation not showing in Render

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

My DopeSheet Animation is not showing in the Rendering.

It´s my first Character in Blender that is sculpted, retopologized, rigged and finally i`ve tested a little animation.

The Modifiers are set to visible and i also tried baking the animations.
I`ve not find a similliar problem on the internet where these two solutions didnt work.

Rendering the Viewport is working fine.

Can anyone help me?

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1keW2T5OoXwA5K9y2LDKfIe3YmhjxXXpJ/view?usp=sharing)

[image: 3D Image]

Answer (score 2):

You also need to enable the render visibility of the *GeometryNodes* modifier of the head object:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!